# Error: Tensor must have a shape comprised of positive integers but got shape [100,]

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, mobilenet, tensorflow-ssd

To get help from the community, we encourage using Stack Overflow and the [`tensorflow.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) tag.

Browser version

not in the browser, using Node command

Describe the problem or feature request

I am using tensorflow.js of **coco-SSD for mobilenet v2**
when I am using the pre-trained model [coco-ssd] it's working perfectly fine, see the below code

```
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const cocoSsd = require('./coco-ssd.js'); 
const fs = require('fs');
const readImage = path => {
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
    const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
    return tfimage;
  }
  const objectDetection = async path => {
    const image = readImage(path);
    const loadlModelPromise = await cocoSsd.load({base: "mobilenet_v2"})
    const result = await loadlModelPromise.detect(image);
    console.log('Classification Results:', result);
  }
  objectDetection(process.argv[2]);
```

while calling the above code `node filename.js ./testImage.png` it gives the desired result.

Now I have a custom trained coco-ssd model which i have converted to tensorflow.js format using the below command
`**tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='num_detections,detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes' --signature_name=serving_default --saved_model_tags=serve ./saved_model ./`
**
once i have the converted **model.json** i wrote the below code for inference on the custom converted model.

```
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const cocoSsd = require('./coco-ssd.js'); 
const fs = require('fs');
const readImage = path => {
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
    const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
    return tfimage;
  }
  const objectDetection = async path => {
    const image = readImage(path);
    const modelUrl = 'file:///Users/xx/model.json'
    const loadlModelPromise = await cocoSsd.load({base: "mobilenet_v2",modelUrl: modelUrl})
    const result = await loadlModelPromise.detect(image);
    console.log('Classification Results:', result);
  }
  objectDetection(process.argv[2]);
```

now when I am running the above code `node fileName.js ./testImage.png` getting the bellow error

(node:32504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: **Error: Tensor must have a shape comprised of positive integers but got shape [100,].**
    at assert (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\util.js:105:15)
    at C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\util.js:646:9
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Object.assertNonNegativeIntegerDimensions (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\util.js:645:11)
    at makeTensor (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\ops\tensor_ops.js:73:16)
    at Object.tensor2d (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\ops\tensor_ops.js:189:12)
    at C:\Users\xx\tfJs\tensorflowJs Classifier\coco-ssd.js:17:7039
    at C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\engine.js:388:22
    at Engine.scopedRun (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\engine.js:398:23)
    at Engine.tidy (C:\Users\xx\tfJs\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\engine.js:387:21)

please help :-)

Comment: Can you please indicate what is the shape of `image` ?

Comment: image.shape: [ 327, 547, 3 ]

Comment: The error has to do with your model that you are loading. What does contain model.json ?

Comment: I Used the trained model from here -> [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz) and converted the saved_model using tensorflowjs_converter, which produced the model.json

Comment: Did you try loading the model using `tf.loadGraphModel` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, its able to load the model.
But when I am doing 
`const output = await loadlModelPromise.executeAsync(image);
console.log(output);`

i am getting [
  Tensor {
    kept: false,
    isDisposedInternal: false,
    shape: [ 1, 100, 4 ],
    dtype: 'float32',
    size: 400,
    strides: [ 400, 4 ],
    dataId: {},
    id: 2504,
    rankType: '3',
    scopeId: 2516
  },
  Tensor {..

not able to interpret this, do you know this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208122/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-mithilesh).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue @edkeveked. Could you help?

Comment: @ClaretNnamocha, could you please ask your question in a new thread and let me know about it ?

Comment: You can follow the status on GitHub  Issue -> https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2766